# Update model from different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to update my vehicle model from my maintenance_controller. How do I do this? Or is this the wrong approach? My maintenance view grabs the odometer value which should be stored in the vehicle model.

```
class Maintenance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle
```

maintenance_controller:

```
@maintenance = Maintenance.new
@maintenance.invoice = params[:invoice]
....
@vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])
@vehicle.odometer = params[:odometer]
....
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why this code would not work. You could use `nested_resources` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicle` in your Maintenance model in order to let Rails deal with the Vehicle update without having to find it and udpate it.

Comment: forgot to add `@vehicle.save` Obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`@vehicle.save`

As @MrYoshiji pointed out, the code is fine, just needed to save it.

Answer (score 0):

When it relates to a potentially-complex user action, I'm a big fan of `Form Objects`. *as seen at* http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/.

I find it helpful to know that user interaction and ActiveRecord definitions are separate.

For example, you could create a MaintenanceForm class.  This would serve to validate the user input and persist it back to the database.

```
class MaintenanceForm
  include Virtus

  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attribute :vehicle, Vehicle
  attribute :odometer_reading, Integer

  validates :vehicle,    presence: true
  validates :maintenace, presence: true
  validate  :odometer_is_increasing
  # … more validations, as needed …

  # Forms are never themselves persisted
  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def save
    if valid?
      persist!
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

private

  def odometer_is_increasing
    # ensure that we don't accept an odometer reading less than our last record, if applicable
  end

  # Do all of the persistence heavy-lifting here.
  def persist!
    Maintenance.create({
      vehicle_id: vehicle.id,
      odometer: odometer_reading
      #
      # ...include others, as needed
    })
    vehicle.update_attributes({
      odometer: odometer_reading
      #
      # ...include others, as needed
    })
  end
end
```

A nested_resource solution would work, too.  But I find nested_resources too convenient and lead to increased coupling / difficult to maintain code.  Though, your mileage may vary.